# Does .NET Framework 4.0 require restart?

Tags: asp.net

Getting .NET 4.0 installed on our prod server, just a quick question, does installation of the framework require restart?  I don't remember anymore! :)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

No, it does not require a restart.

Comment: Because it's not always true

Comment: This is false, it can require a restart. See my answer.

Comment: to me "required" == "always" so if it's not always true, then it's not required.

Answer (score 16):

It can require a restart.

> The .NET Framework setup will require a reboot when one of the files
>   it needs to install is in use during installation.  There are a
>   handful of files that are shared by all versions of the .NET
>   Framework, so if there is an earlier version of the .NET Framework
>   installed on the system than the one that is currently being
>   installed, and a managed application is running and holding one of the
>   shared files in use, then a reboot could be required at the end of
>   installation.

More details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/06/13/627729.aspx).

Answer (score 14):

It depends.... It depends on how up to date the computer is, what else is installed. There are too many factors to actually know for certain. My experience is we have installed it on 7 machines both 32 and 64 bit running Server 2003 & 2007 some required a reboot and others did not.

Answer (score 11):

If a reboot is needed, you'll find two entries in System event viewer, like:

> Event id: 4376
>
> Servicing has required reboot to complete the operation of setting package KB956250(Update) into Install Requested(Install Requested) state

and

> Event id: 4386
>
> Windows Servicing required reboot to complete the process of changing update NetFx4x86 from package KB956250(Update) into Install Requested(Install Requested) state

Answer (score 0):

Not required to do a restart On Windows 10 version after installing dot net version 4.7.1
If it needs to be reflected on your Visual Studio, which requires you to restart the Visual Studio alone to reflect the changes.